# How to have a custom alignment guide permeate a ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, alignment

I want to be able to align things in a `ZStack`. Some of these things are in a `ScrollView` in the `ZStack`, and some are not. I can get the things that are in the `ScrollView` to align with each other, and things outside the `ScrollView` to align with each other, but I cannot get them to all align. I can do if I just remove the `ScrollView`, so for instance:

```
extension VerticalAlignment {
    enum MidAccountAndName: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            d[.top]
        }
    }
    
    static let midAccountAndName = VerticalAlignment(MidAccountAndName.self)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .midAccountAndName)) {
            Rectangle()
                .alignmentGuide(.midAccountAndName) { d in
                    d[VerticalAlignment.center]
                }
                .frame(width: 1000, height: 2)
            
                HStack(alignment: .midAccountAndName) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Left-hand text")
                            .alignmentGuide(.midAccountAndName) { d in
                                d[VerticalAlignment.center]
                            }
                        Text("More text")
                    }
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text("Right-hand text")
                        Text("Title")
                            .alignmentGuide(.midAccountAndName) { d in
                                d[VerticalAlignment.center]
                            }
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results in this, which is what I want:

[image: aligned views in swiftui]

But this code:

```
extension VerticalAlignment {
    enum MidAccountAndName: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            d[.top]
        }
    }
    
    static let midAccountAndName = VerticalAlignment(MidAccountAndName.self)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .midAccountAndName)) {
            Rectangle()
                .alignmentGuide(.midAccountAndName) { d in
                    d[VerticalAlignment.center]
                }
                .frame(width: 1000, height: 2)
            
            ScrollView {
                HStack(alignment: .midAccountAndName) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Left-hand text")
                            .alignmentGuide(.midAccountAndName) { d in
                                d[VerticalAlignment.center]
                            }
                        Text("More text")
                    }
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text("Right-hand text")
                        Text("Title")
                            .alignmentGuide(.midAccountAndName) { d in
                                d[VerticalAlignment.center]
                            }
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results in this, which is undesirable:

[image: unaligned views in swiftui]

Can anyone help me get the former behaviour working in concert with the `ScrollView`?

Comment: I am curious, why does it have to be in a ZStack? You appear to be lining things up side by side, which is a job for an HStack.

Comment: I don't know how I could have the rectangle overlay the HStack without using a ZStack?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

[image: Aligned View]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let largeFont = Font.largeTitle
    let smallFont = Font.body

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("|")
                        .font(largeFont)
                        .frame(width: 0)
                    Text("Left-hand text")
                    Text("More Text")
                }
                .font(smallFont)
            }
            
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Right-hand text")
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title")
                            .font(largeFont)
                    }
                }
                .font(smallFont)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is to use a placeholder at `width: 0` on the other side of the HStack in your VStacks. I made the font variables so that you could change the relative sizes without accidentally messing up the alignment. There is usually a simple way in SwiftUI to achieve your layout, and let the OS do the work for you.